# Cogs in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discogs-api

So I've made a discord bot with a lot of commands (I'll show one only here to make it clearer), but the code is now really messy. I've always wanted to move the commands into a seperate folder names cogs with files in it. But it doesn't seem to work:

`main.py`:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "m.", intents = intents)

token = "1234567890"

cogs = ["ping"]
for cog in cogs:
  try:
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog.lower()}')
    print(f'{cog} cog loaded.')
  except Exception as e:
    print(f'Failed to load {cog} cog: {e}')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
  
try:
  bot.run(token)
except discord.HTTPException as e:
    if e.status == 429:
        print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
        print("Get help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724687/in-discord-py-how-to-solve-the-error-for-toomanyrequests")
    else:
        raise e
```

`ping.py`:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        message = await ctx.send('Pong!')
        latency = self.bot.latency * 1000  # Convert to milliseconds
        await message.edit(content=f'Pong! **{latency:.2f} ms**')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

But this is what it shows:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdpev.png)
I've tried making it `await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog.lower()}')` But it just throws another error at me:
[error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMdim.png)
I am wondering wether I should put the `await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog.lower()}')` into a `async def` function. But I don't know how to do that, and when I should call the function.
Also, this is what is shown in the console:

```
/home/runner/Python-Discord-Bot/main.py:14: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog.lower()}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
ping cog loaded.
2024-03-26 10:47:57 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2024-03-26 10:47:58 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).
We have logged in as xxx#9743
```

I've already looked at [Cogs discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583557/cogs-discord-py) but the answers just either use `bot.load_extension('maincog')` or `client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')`, which doesn't help since it doesn't use await and isn't in a function.
I've also looked at [discord.py How i make cogs in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75177934/discord-py-how-i-make-cogs-in-discord-py) and tried out the solutions that Noob_Coder_GALAXY gave, but then, it throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Python-Discord-Bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 947, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Python-Discord-Bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Python-Discord-Bot/main.py", line 20, in on_ready
    await preload()
  File "/home/runner/Python-Discord-Bot/main.py", line 16, in preload
    await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
  File "/home/runner/Python-Discord-Bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1013, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/home/runner/Python-Discord-Bot/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 952, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.ping' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

I've already made sure that the `ping.py` in in the folder `cogs` and everything, so now the only problem is the code. Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi, the `setup` in each cog must be **async** and the `load_extension` too (use **await**)

Comment: So you mean for the `ping.py` in `cogs` should be 
```
async def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```
or
```
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```
and how can I make a `load_extension` `await`?

Comment: You can have a look on an official example regarding an advanced startup [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/advanced_startup.py).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use extensions/cogs in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165811/how-to-use-extensions-cogs-in-discord-py)